# Check if DateTime is in the future with old version of JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime, legacy

I have a unique situation. I'm working on a legacy project that is on an old WebLogic server that (A) does not allow anything past Java 6, and (B) pollutes the classloader with an old version of JodaTime (version 1.2, to be precise).

The client I'm working for has a Standard Development Platform that includes Java 8, and JodaTime for projects that are stuck in earlier versions of Java.  Therefore, I'm stuck using this old version of JodaTime (310-Backport would be a great solution, but I'm not allowed to use it).

I need to create a utility method that checks if a `DateTime` is after today (regardless of time). JodaTime 1.2 does not have `LocalDate`, or convenient static factory methods like `now()`, so I have come up with this:

```
public static boolean isAfterToday(DateTime dateTime) {
  YearMonthDay date = new YearMonthDay(dateTime);
  YearMonthDay today = new YearMonthDay();
  return date.isAfter(today);
}
```

It feels a bit icky because in more recent versions of JodaTime, everything in the `YearMonthDay` class has been deprecated and replaced with `LocalDate`, which sadly I can't use. Is there a better way I can do this?  Also, I'm trying to strip the time off the `DateTime` by converting it to a `YearMonthDay`... are there any "gotchas" I'm missing or should be aware of?

A couple of additional notes: I'm assuming that I've already null-checked the `dateTime` argument, and the time zone shouldn't be an issue because all time zones in the application are GMT.  Also, I *am* allowed to use the Apache Commons and Guava libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sure that all time zones are GMT, the most trivial implementation would be:

```
public static boolean isAfterToday(DateTime dateTime) {
    String dateTimeStr = dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String nowStr = new DateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return dateTimeStr.compareTo(nowStr) > 0;
}
```

You can slightly optimize it like this:

```
private static final DateTimeFormat yearMonthDay = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

public static boolean isAfterToday(DateTime dateTime) {
    String dateTimeStr = yearMonthDay.print(dateTime);
    String nowStr = yearMonthDay.print(new DateTime());
    return dateTimeStr.compareTo(nowStr) > 0;
}
```

That solution decouples you a bit from JodaTime in a way that it does not introduce another date/time type.

On the other hand, the deprecation note on `YearMonthDay` says

> Use LocalDate which has a much better internal implementation

so it might be that it's not exactly *wrong* to use it and I would not assume that you run into any errors by using it.

I suggest writing a nice ([parameterized](https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams)?) set of unit tests for that method and validate the behaviour of `YearMonthDay`. If it seems to work, then go with it, if it does not, then try the `toString()` workaround.

Comment: Interesting.  It hadn't occurred to me before to compare the String representation.  If years aren't padded this would produce incorrect results for most years prior to 1000 AD or after 9999 AD, but I'm not worried about that.